# ignore `assets` folder from ng build --prod

Tags: angular

I want not to include `assets` folder in

> ng build --prod

But `assets` folder shall be available when i am running

```
ng serve
```

I tried writing as below:

```
apps:[
   exclude: ["assets"]
]
```

But this did not work.
Tried the solution as below as well

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5435

But none of it is working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar scenario, since I didn't want to copy the assets folder when building using aot.
After finding [this article](https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/), I ended up duplicating my app config at the .angular-cli.json, each one with its unique name (in my case *devApp* and *aotApp*) like this:

```
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"project": {
    "name": "my-project"
},
"apps": [
    {
        "name": "devApp",
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "wwwroot",
        "assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico"
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
        "test": "test.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "prefix": "app",
        "styles": [
            "styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
        ],
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
        "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        "name": "aotApp",
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "wwwroot",
        "assets": [
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
        "test": "test.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "prefix": "app",
        "styles": [
            "styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
        ],
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
        "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    }
],
--- and then the rest of the configuration
```

So... to develop I use `ng serve --app devApp` (although It seems that just `ng serve` also works), and when I need to generate the bundles for production, I run `ng build --app aotApp --prod`.

Comment: I'm working with different Angular projects. Do you know how that works? I'm working with Angular CLI 7.0.5. See my StackOverflow question for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121020/angular-cli-7-0-5-different-assets-for-development-and-production

Comment: I haven't upgraded to Angular 7 yet (I'm waiting for Ivy to be ready), however, with Angular 6.0.9 this still works if your angular.json is configured this way.

Answer (score -1):

Add asset in angular-cli.json file to excludes the assets folder in production when you type ng build --prod like this

```
"apps": [
        {
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "AngularApp",
            "assets": [

              ],
              }
       ]
```

`ng serve`  assets folder will be available

Comment: this answer does not demonstrate to exclude `assets` folder from build prod. This approach i already tried and i am not getting assets while running `ng serve`. Can you try to exlpain more

Comment: I am using this approach only for exclude assets folder files, in above code assets is empty.so I am getting the assets folder in production but it will remove all the files in assets

Comment: that is true but i am not getting folder or files by this approach even in `ng serve`

Comment: not clear.what you are asking.with `ng serve` you wont get 'dist' folder rt? then where you are checking the assets folder?

Comment: say, i have theme files in `assets/theme` folder and i want that theme file shall only load for `ng serve` not for `ng build --prod`

Comment: if you want theme files just add the `assets/theme` in assets `"assets:["assets/theme",..]"`

Comment: I do not know if i m unable to explain or you are not getting the problem statement

Comment: did you find a way ? I'm facing the same issue, I'd like to remove assets/ from my build, but keep it with ng serve.