# Exclude file in /assets folder after ng build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a configuration file - assets/config.json. How can I exclude this file after running 
`ng build --configuration production`?

I've tried editing ts.config.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      "src/app/assets/**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

but it still saves the assets folder in dist folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ignore \`assets\` folder from ng build --prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795360/ignore-assets-folder-from-ng-build-prod)

Comment: "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      "**/assets/*"
    ]